# Why is my Docker PHP container printing to CLI then exiting?

Tags: php, docker, apache, containers

I'm a Docker noob so bear with me if this is basic. I'm trying to write spin up a simple PHP container that I can visit via localhost to see a simple output message.

Instead, however, my output appears in the console after I run `docker run` and the container immediately stops, and isn't browser-visitable. What am I doing wrong?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-apache
CMD [ "php", "./index.php" ]
```

Build image:

```
docker build -t php-setup .
```

Run container - mounting index.php while doing so:

```
docker run -p 80:80 --name php-setup-cntnr -v "$(PWD):/var/www/html" php-setup
```

index.php:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello!';
```

Output in terminal straight after `docker run ...`:

```
Hello!
```

How can I get the container to stay up, and be visitable in the browser?

[ --- EDIT --- ]

Further to Hitesh's answer, it's clear I'm missing the `-d` param. However this doesn't solve my problem.

This results in a hash string being output after the `docker run` command, and my PHP output going to the container's log. But my container is still showing as 'exited' in Docker Desktop and thus isn't visitable in the browser.

[ ---- EDIT 2 ---- ]

**As far as I can tell, there is nothing in the accepted answer on the marked dup that explains how to resolve this. Its main argument is to use PHP with Apache, which I'm already doing.**

Comment: Your line `CMD [ "php", "./index.php" ]` is saying run this and the container then exits.

Comment: Thank you. I've read the accepted answer on the dup, and I can't seem to see anything that sticks out that explains why their container should stay up (visitable in a browser) and mine quits. Could you kindly tell me what controls that factor?

Comment: Run Apache service in the forground

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate, bearing in mind I said I was a noob? Or I'm happy to go read stuff.

Comment: There is nothing in the accepted answer on the marked dup that explains how to resolve this. As far as I can tell, I'm already doing what they're doing. Its main argument is to use PHP with Apache, which I'm already doing.